# problem with dice

Tags: probability

Let X be the number of tosses of a dice to obtain the first even number.

and Y the number of tosses of the same dice to obtain the first number >3.

Both X and Y are geometric random variable with mean equals to 2.

I have to determine $P(X>2|Y=2)$

$$P(X>2|Y=2)=\frac{P((X>2)\cap(Y=2))}{P(Y=2)}=\frac{P((Y=2)|(X>2))*P(X>2)}{P(Y=2)}$$

$P((Y=2)|(X>2))=1/6$ because it is the probability that it is drawn 5 in the second draw
$$P((X>2))=1-P(X=1)-P(X=2)=1- \frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$$

$$P((Y=2))= \frac{1}{4} $$
and then my final result is $ \frac{1}{6}$

But the solution suggested  has this result

$$P((X>2)\cap(Y=2))=1/18$$ that I don't understand.(the final result is $\frac{2}{9}$).
is it right? and am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it should be instead
$$
\Pr(X > 2 \mid Y = 2) = \frac{\Pr(Y = 2 \mid X > 2)\cdot\Pr(X > 2)}{\Pr(Y = 2)}
$$
Conditioned on $X > 2$, $Y = 2$ implies that the first roll is either $3$ or $1$ and the second roll is $5$. Therefore, the probability is
$$
\Pr(Y = 2 \mid X > 2) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{9}
$$
As you have calculated,
$$
\Pr(X > 2) = \frac{1}{4} \quad\text{and}\quad \Pr(Y = 2) = \frac{1}{4}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\Pr(X > 2 \mid Y = 2) = \frac{2}{9}
$$

Comment: please look at my post, I've edited the result for $P(Y=2 \cap  X>2)$    How can you explain that it is 1/18?

Comment: @Anne Right. $\Pr(X > 2, Y = 2) = \Pr(X > 2 \mid Y = 2) \cdot \Pr(Y = 2) = \frac{2}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{18}$.

Comment: and if I want to calculate $P(X>2,Y=2) = P((1,5))+P((3,5))=1/6*1/6+1/6*1/6=1/18$?

Comment: @Anne Of course. It is the other way to compute $P(X > 2, Y=2)$. Actually, we have $P((1, 5)) = P((3, 5)) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$.